VBA array dynamically sized
I have a function whereby I am trying to create an insert into statement by saving the column names from a select and using that output to write the insert into. So I try to create a 2- dimensional array filling the first slot with the areas (651,652 and 801) and the 2nd slot with the column name, which I can get from a select.
So my function starts like this:
Function create_insert() as boolean

Dim arrCol(0 to 2, 0 to 75) as variant

Dim A(0 to 2) as variant

A(0) = "65"
A(1) = "66"
A(2) = "80"

Set dbs=currentdb()

For i = lbound(A) to 2

Set rs= dbs.openrecordset("select...". & A(i))

Do while not rs.eof

  ArrCol(i,0) = A(i)
  ArrCol(i,i+j)=rs(0).Value
  J=j +1
  rs.movenext
Loop

Next i


But I'm having problems with the dimensions of the array. As I would like it more dynamic instead of the 75 I have statically defined it as.
By the way it's 3 tables (areas-65,66,80) that I'm getting the columns from, so I need both information,the table and column.
I also have a general table called "creator", where each field is a row and a column called area, which is obviously either 65,66 or 80.. The areas.

You want array 2nd dimension dependent on how many records are in recordset? Get RecordCount and use Redim to define array size. Should declare all variables.

So do I need to go through the 3 selects first, add up the numbers and redim, or can I do the redim inside the For loop?

Redim after opening recordset and getting RecordCount.

An INSERT sql action should be possible without use of array objects. Why do you have 3 tables for areas instead of one table with a field for area identifier? Are field names saved in field called with rs(0).Value? Edit question to show sample data and desired result as formatted text tables.

I have columns from three 3 tables. So in the end I'll have an insert into end_table( [all columns] ) with values coming from my status which are from 3 tables. In short, information from 3 tables are being merged into one.

Yes, girlfriend are stored in rs(0).value. There is only one column output from my select, which is dynamic, hence rs(0). Value

I'm open for suggestions on a better way to do this altogether..

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You could just loop the fields collection of the recordset object. No array needed IMO.

Unless Function returns a value or needs to be called by macro, could just be a Sub.
Declare array without dimensions then Redim based on recordset Recordcount.
Sub create_insert()

Dim arrCol() As Variant
Dim A(0 To 2) As Variant
Dim dbs As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer, j As Integer

A(0) = "651"
A(1) = "652"
A(2) = "801"

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

For i = 0 To 2
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [" & A(i) & "]")
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst
    ReDim arrCol(3, rs.RecordCount)
    j = 1
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        arrCol(i, 0) = A(i)
        arrCol(i, j) = rs(0).Value
        Debug.Print arrCol(i, 0), arrCol(i, j)
        j = j + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Next i
End Sub


it works. So thanks for that...the Arrays are not so tidy, but I guess thats due to my own constellation of (i,j) and (i,0)
